# parallelise web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have written a python script to scrape data date wise from a particular website.. the thing is the application is taking very long as i have years of data to scrape through.
The work around i am currently using is to execute the script multiple times with date ranges, but i am required to log into the site multiple times which is not the best way i know.

the code is as follows

```
import requests
import datetime
username = 'xxxxx'
passwrod = 'yyyyy'
startday = datetime(1950,1,1)
endday = datetime.(2018,1,1)
processday = startday
session1 = logintospartan(username,password)

while(processday<endday):
    responcecode = scrapedatafordate(session1,processday)
    processday = processday +datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

each day takes an hour to process given this is 50 years worth of data that is atleast 18000+ hours of time which is rediculous Is there a way i can run the 'while' snippet multiple times in parallel

Here is a working example of the code

```
import requests
try:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

queryk = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
i = len(queryk)
s = requests.session()
query_url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q='
while(i>0):
    r = s.get(query_url+queryk[-i])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    h3 = soup.find_all('h3')
    for q in h3:
        links = q.find_all('a')
        for a in links:
            print(a['href'])
    i = i-1
```

can a parallelize the loop?

Comment: What do you exaclty mean with "scraping"? When this means "requesting and retriving data from a server" you should take "asyncrone programming" (e.g. `asyncio`) into account. If it means "computing data on your local machine" you should look in the topic "Mutlithreading" (e.g. `threading`).

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example!

Comment: I am requesting data from the server. i need to navigate through a complex site structure to get the exact data i need where i am finally downloading 1000's of small (10-20kb files) the function 'scrapedatafordate' auto navigates and identifies the relevent data for me. i need a way to run this function multiple times in parallel so yes i need multithreading as well as multi web session

Comment: Don't explain. Provide example code. Your code must work out-of-the-box. You can simulate your tasks with `time.sleep()` and/or `for`-loops.

Comment: working example pasted in post above

Comment: Have you tested your code? It is not "working". `soup` is always `None`. And you still don't user correct letters (uppercase) and interpunction even not in your subject heading!

Comment: About the topic of Threading and Mutliprocessing please read this great presentation: http://www.dabeaz.com/usenix2009/concurrent/

Comment: the code works as is in pycharm